# Building Air Apps (Desktop) with Haxe - Steps

Tags: air, haxe

I'm a developer in ActionScript and while I'm watching Haxe as a language to be used by me, since besides the resemblance ActionScript, still be possible to make applications with output to flash yet. 
However I have a question about building AIR packages. When I search about building AIR applications with Haxe, the search does not bring satisfactory results. 
I ask, after the codification and development of the code (in Haxe), how is it possible to transform what was built into an AIR package?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a very popular topic it seems. Anyhow, as far as I remember my experience building it some years ago, what you need would be:

1. If you need some air-specific APIs then you should write externs for them. There is [this](https://code.google.com/p/haxeair/) existing project, but it would need a bit of update as it was written for flash9, however, I believe it is doable in like 1 hour of work.
2. Compile to flash.
3. Write all the manifests you need for Air. (Sorry, don't remember what exactly it needs.)
4. Use [this guides](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd9.html) to package(also test and sign) your apps.

Note: If you want to go the same way you did before, you could compile haxe to as3 and be happy. However, I wouldn't recommend this method due to loosing speed and probable implications which may arrive.